# Angularjs tutorial step2 test chrome not start with Error write EIO

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

My pc is Windows7 32bit.
When I test Angularjs tutorial step2.
Chrome not start with error.

--- versions ---
Angularjs:1.0.2
testacular:0.4.0

--- messages ----

```
 info: Testacular server started at http://localhost:9876/
    info (launcher): Starting browser chrome
    error (launcher):
    events.js:71
            throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                           ^
    Error: write EIO
        at errnoException (net.js:770:11)
        at Object.afterWrite (net.js:594:19)
```

Comment: Solved this problem.
set CHROME_BIN=C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer: https://github.com/angular/ang...

start scripts/test.sh (*on windows: scripts\test.bat*)

In the Git Shell / command window, go to the angular-phonecat directory. Enter this command

**scripts\test.bat**

Please note it test.bat and not .sh file.

You can see that the server
started but it may throw error that Chrome cannot be started and it is unable to find the path. I too was stopped at this point and anyhow after several reference, got this solution.

Open **config/testacular.conf.js** in some editor. Change the

browsers = ['Chrome'] to

**browsers = ['C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'];**

(This is where my Chrome is installed in Windows 8). You may need to get the correct installation path along with the chrome.exe in path and should use forward-slash
otherwise it will not work.

It is working for me now!

Comment: Yeah, it works, but unfortunately, the config files get overwritten when you reset the project to move to the next lesson :(